# Intellij Plugin - can i access the contents of the open editor window?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Building an intellij plugin.

How do i access the contents of an open window? For example, if "HelloWorld.java" is open, and a user runs my plugin, I would like to be able to, say, read the contents of the HelloWorld.java file.

What is some sample java plugin code - if any - to just get the currently open file?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/editor_basics/working_with_text.html

Comment: Please read the plugin development documentation: https://github.com/jetbrains/intellij-sdk-docs

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of a file, you should get an instance of the `Document` class. Then you can call `document.getText()` to get it's contents. As an example, you can get a `document` instance from `editor`, which you can get from `AnActionEvent`.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {
    Editor editor = event.getRequiredData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);
    Document document = editor.getDocument();
    String contents = document.getText();
}
```